# Have some troubles vith xml file. Android. Eclipse. error: Invalid start tag PreferenceScreen

Tags: java, android, xml

Have some troubles vith xml file. Android. Eclipse. Help please)
Error: error: Invalid start tag PreferenceScreen

Error notification on second line

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Работа с файлами">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="@string/pref_openmode"
            android:title="Открыть файл"
            android:summary="Открывать файл при запуске приложения" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

(its only a little bit part...)

Comment: You probably have it in the *wrong folder*. Put it inside `/res/xml` and check.

Comment: if you actually have spaces preceeding the xml declaration, try removing them

Comment: And make sure you close `</PreferenceScreen>` at the end and that you've definitely saved the file in the utf-8 encoding.

Comment: make sure you have Android API level >= 18.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have your file in the wrong directory.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Работа с файлами">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="@string/pref_openmode"
            android:title="Открыть файл"
            android:summary="Открывать файл при запуске приложения" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Работа с файлами">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="@string/pref_openmode"
        android:title="Открыть файл"
        android:summary="Открывать файл при запуске приложения" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
       </PreferenceScreen>
```

The above is correct u should place this xml file in the values which is under res folder.

Comment: Bad answer. This should have been deleted or dowvoted as induces the users into errors